# Override page title for Tracker module pages in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I read through a few posts about `hook_form_alter()` but couldn't make this work.

I want to create a custom module to override a menu `$items` 'title' for the Drupal core Tracker module.

```
function tracker_menu() {
  // ....
  $items['user/%user/track'] = array(
    'title' => 'Track',
    'page callback' => 'tracker_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1, TRUE),
    'access callback' => '_tracker_user_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'tracker.pages.inc',
  );
  // ...
}
```

I tried

```
function mymodule_tracker_menu_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $items['user/%user/track']['title'] = 'Recent Content';
}
```

Comment: also tried declaring variable with `function mymodule_tracker_menu_form_alter(&$items){` instead

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong hook. You have to use [`hook_menu_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x). `hook_form_alter()` is for forms.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {

  $items['user/%user/track']['title callback'] = '_MYCALLBACK';
}

/**
 * Custom title callback.
 */
function _MYCALLBACK() {

  return t('Recent Content');
}
```

You could also use a preprocess function from your theme's `template.php` for that (actually much better, see [`template_process_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_page/7.x)):

```
/**
 * Implements template_process_page().
 */
function MYTEMPLATE_process_page(&$variables) {

  if (arg(0) === 'user' && arg(2) === 'track) {

    $variables['title'] = t('Recent Content');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, i tried both but didn't work. 
#1 complains about the last `{` being unexpected lol no idea why and 
#2 `syntax error, unexpected 'title' (T_STRING)`

Comment: @Markus – Typo. #1 lacked a `;`. And #2 you are right it must be the `_process_` hook instead :)

Comment: @Markus – Updated

Comment: I think #2 also missed ' after 'track? but still unexpected '}' (2nd last)
and #1 no errors but didn't change the title.

Comment: for #2 is $variables correct instead of using $items?

Comment: @Markus – It's `$variables` yes, like it's written in the docs. #1 might not work because the order of module implements not ideal. Then you have to ensure your module runs last via this hook https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x Please read the docs behind the links I provided.

Comment: @Markus – And then flush the cache a thousand times ;)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at #1 , would that be same issue for #2?

Comment: @Markus – No, if you implement that hook in your theme's template.php. Yes, if you implement it from within a custom module.

Comment: ah that makes sense, thanks, I will try #1, might be easier (better practice?) for future upgrades to import custom modules :)